# Why won't search function correctly return a pointer?

Tags: templates, c++11, pointers

I need some help with my code. The function findNode lies within a header file, and is called in the main. As you can see, findNode calls itself until it finds the correct data value in each of the nodes. The type of tree implemented is a General Tree.
My problem is that the function does find the TreeNode it needs to find, but it returns it incorrectly. The data value of p in main is empty

```
TreeNode<Type>* findNode(Type &_data, TreeNode<Type>* _ptr)
{

    if(_ptr->data == _data)
    {
        cout << "ptr->data: " << _ptr->showData() << endl;
        return _ptr;
    } 
    if(_ptr->children != NULL)
    {
        findNode(_data, _ptr->children->getHead());
    }
    if(_ptr->getNext() != NULL)
    {
        findNode(_data, _ptr->getNext());
    }

}


In MAIN:
.
.
        case 3:
        {
            string data;
            cout << "****************" << endl;
            cout << "***findNode()***" << endl;
            cout << "Data to find: " << endl;
            cin >> data;

            TreeNode<string>* p = Tree->findNode(data, Tree->getRoot());

            cout << "p->data = " << p->showData() << endl;

            break;
        }
```

Comment: Avoid using CAPS so much.

Answer (score 1):

add "return" in front of  findNode(..) to fix the issue.

```
    if(_ptr->children != NULL)
    {
        return findNode(_data, _ptr->children->getHead());
    }
    if(_ptr->getNext() != NULL)
    {
        return findNode(_data, _ptr->getNext());
    }
```

unless the data matches in the first time, it is not returned. it is merely called and the result is let go.

In your original code, Say the data is matched in 4 th level of function call: 
findNode1->findNode2->findNode3->findNode4 
then this happens:
findNode4 returns ptr to findNode3, which does not return anything as it just called the function without expecting any value back.

At your level of skill it is very good to practice "uniform coding" :

```
      retval = _ptr;
}
else if(_ptr->children != NULL)
{
     retval = findNode(_data, _ptr->children->getHead());
}
else if(_ptr->getNext() != NULL)
{
     retval = findNode(_data, _ptr->getNext());
}
return retval;  // return from single point.
```

it is merely a style not technically better, but imho gradual learning is better.